# »Es braucht« statt »man braucht«

Tags: pronoun, regional

In den letzten Wochen fällt mir immer öfter auf, dass in Sätzen, in denen früher »man braucht« gesagt wurde, seit neuestem »es braucht« verwendet wird.

> früher: »Wenn das so ist, dann braucht *man* keine Regierung mehr.
>   heute: »Wenn das so ist, dann braucht *es* keine Regierung mehr.

(Soeben in einer Nachrichtensendung im österreichischen Fernsehen gehört.)

Andere Beispiele:

> früher: Braucht *man* die EU noch?
>   heute: Braucht *es* die EU noch?
>
> früher: Hier, in dieser Region, bräuchte *man* dringend mehr Regen.
>   heute: Hier, in dieser Region, bräuchte *es* dringend mehr Regen.

Mir ist dieses »es braucht« bisher nur im schweizerischen Deutsch aufgefallen. Anscheinend breitet es sich auch in Österreich aus.

Wie ist die Situation in anderen Regionen?
Wie ist dieses »es« grammatisch zu bewerten? (Generell in solchen Sätzen, und speziell auch im Vergleich mit dem »man«.)

Comment: In meinem Dialekt (Südwestdeutschland) ist "Es braucht etwas..." vollkommen gängig - "seit immer". Der Duden führt ein Beispiel (*Es braucht nur einen Wink...* bzw. sogar *...es braucht keines Beweises...*) auf, ohne es auf eine Region zu beschränken. Bedenke, dass "man" immer auf eine Person anspielt - "Es braucht Regen" eben nicht.

Comment: Ich kenne diese Formulierung auch "schon immer", obwohl ich sie bewusst keinem Dialekt zuordnen kann. Es ist definitiv keine neuere Entwicklung.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist das i.W. süddeutscher Dialekt, und damit auch in Österreich und der deutschsprachigen Schweiz gebräuchlich.
Der Unterschied für mich liegt immer darin, dass "man braucht" eine Menge von Menschen impliziert (die Umkehrung ist dann "niemand braucht"), während "es braucht" die reine Notwendigkeit ausdrückt (die Umkehrung ist dann "ist nicht nötig").

Comment: @TvF: Nein, das ist eben, zumindest bisher, in Österreich nicht gängig. Ich habe mit "es braucht" bisher nur schweizerisches Deutsch (sowohl Dialekt als auch Hochdeutsch) in Verbindung gebracht, höre das nun aber immer wieder in den Nachrichtensendungen des ORF. Im täglichen Gespräch ist mir das weder in Wien noch in St. Pölten untergekommen.

Comment: @dirkt: Kannst du deine Information noch um die Angabe einer Region ergänzen? Obwohl du nun schon fast 3 Jahre hier bist, ist dein Profil leider noch immer völlig jungfräulich, und auch sonst gibst du mir keine Informationen wo genau man diese Formulierung "schon immer" kennt.

Comment: Ich stamme aus der Region Frankfurt/Main, aber empfinde die Formulierung nicht als typisch für diese Region. Ich weiß nicht, woher ich sie kenne, aber ich habe sie bei verschiedensten Gelegenheiten schon gehört, und ich kann mich nicht an eine Zeit erinnern, wo mich die Formulierung überrascht hätte. (Keine Ahnung, ob das hilft, aber du hast gefragt).

Comment: Aus rein grammatikalischer Sicht gibt es keinen Grund, "brauchen" nicht in unpersönlicher Verwendung zu gebrauchen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast hat mE schon recht: natürlich gab es die die Verwendung „immer schon“, aber sie war jdf in Österreich eher selten und dann oft auf bestimmte, feste Formulierungen beschränkt (zB „es braucht mehr als …, um …“). (ETA: _So I'm late to the party. Sue me._)

Comment: Mich persönlich stört die Formulierung, da sie sich durch Interviews mit einem bestimmten Politiker in den Medien verbreitet hat. Plötzlich höre ich diese bei Konferenzen und Ansprachen usw. (Darüber hinaus hat sich die Formulierung "ein Stück weit" ebenfalls in die Sprachgewohnheiten hinein verbreitet ...) Dass "es braucht" aus Gründen des Gendering verwendet wird, ist ein Aspekt, über den ich mir noch keine Gedanken gemacht habe. Möglich wär's.

Comment: Siehe vorige Frage zu "Es sind dies ..." (war glaube auf skeptics.SE). Das war mir wiederum noch nie aufgefallen und war offensichtlich Ostreichisch (zitiert wurde Hitler). Inzwischen habe ich mich sogar dran gewöhnt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im geschriebenen Deutsch würde ich immer eher eine Formulierung im Passiv erwarten, die ohne Pronomen auskommt:

> - Wenn das so ist, *wird* keine Regierung mehr *gebraucht*. (*benötigt*)
> - *Wird* die EU noch *gebraucht*? (*benötigt*)
> - In dieser Region *wird* dringend mehr Regen *gebraucht*. (*benötigt*)

Mit dem etwas „feineren“ *benötigen* statt *brauchen*, welches außerdem nicht die missverständliche Nebenbedeutung ‚verwenden‘ aufweist, ist nur *man*, aber nicht *es* möglich:

> - Wenn das so ist, *benötigt man* keine Regierung mehr. (*benötigt *es*)
> - *Benötigt man* die EU noch? (*benötigt *es*)
> - In dieser Region *benötigt man* dringend mehr Regen. (*benötigt *es*)

Dieses *be*-Verb kann wiederum durch *nötig* oder *notwendig sein* ersetzt werden.

> - Wenn das so ist, *ist* keine Regierung mehr *nötig*. (*notwendig*)
> - *Ist* die EU noch *nötig*? (*notwendig*)
> - In dieser Region *ist* dringend mehr Regen *nötig*. (*notwendig*)

Umgangssprachlich würde ich im Norden des Sprachraums eher *man* erwarten, aber ein passendes (Personal-)Pronomen wirkt noch natürlicher:

> - Wenn das so ist, *braucht ihr* keine Regierung mehr. („*brauchta*“; *brauchst du*, „*brauchste*“)
> - *Brauchen wir* die EU noch? („*brauchwa*“)
> - Hier, in dieser Region, *brauchen sie* dringend mehr Regen. (*brauchen die*, „*brauchense*“)

Noch eine Ebene flapsiger wäre *not tun*:

> - Wenn das so ist, *tut* keine Regierung mehr *not*.
> - *Tut* die EU noch *not*?
> - Hier, in dieser Region, *tut* dringend mehr Regen *not*.

Es gibt allerdings Verben (und Phrasen), bei denen *es* ein noch stärkerer Marker für „Süddeutsch“ ist als bei *brauchen*. Man kann *es* allerdings nicht immer durch *man* ersetzen, sondern muss ggf. ein anderes Verb wählen.

> - Hier, in dieser Region, *hat es* nicht genug Regen. (*?hat man* → *gibt es*, *haben sie*)

Subjektives Fazit: *braucht es* oder *braucht’s* fällt im direkten Vergleich als süddeutsch auf und wird kaum aktiv verwendet, wirkt aber im niederdeutschen Sprachraum nicht (mehr) so unnatürlich, dass man drüber stolpern würde.

Comment: Es gibt auch noch: *...bedarf es keiner....*

Comment: Warum sollte ein "benötigt es" nicht möglich sein? In meinen Augen wäre es sogar die formalere Form.

Answer (score 9):

Als jemand aus dem (Süd-) Westen Bayerns, kurz vor der Sprachgrenze zum Schwäbischen, kommt mir *es braucht* überhaupt nicht seltsam vor. Ich bin allerdings auch noch relativ jung, kann also nicht sagen, inwiefern es sich um eine neuartige Entwicklung handelt.

In einem Kommentar hat TvF schön den Unterschied zwischen »es braucht« und »man braucht« herausgearbeitet. Beides lässt sich umkehren, wobei aus »man braucht« ein »niemand braucht« würde, während »es braucht« zu »ist nicht nötig« wird. Das *man* in »man braucht« impliziert also stets, dass es um *Menschen* geht, während *es* auch ein rein abstraktes *benötigen* bedeuten kann.

Ich denke, dass es sich bei *es* um einen »grammatikalischen Expletiv« handelt. Ich muss kurz ausschweifen, um zu erklären, was ich damit meine. In beiden folgenden Sätzen haben wir es mit einem vergleichbaren *es* zu tun, das in keiner Weise Urheber der dargestellten Handlungen ist.

> Es wird heute gefeiert.
>
> Es regnet heute.

Weder ist *es* das abstrakte Wetter, das den Regen bringt, noch tut *es* irgendetwas zur Feier dazu. Die beiden *es* sind also [Expletiva](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum); sie erfüllen rein grammatisch-syntaktische Funktionen. Sie sind aber unterschiedlich, was man an der Umstellung der Sätze sieht:

> Heute wird gefeiert.
>
> Heute regnet **es.**

Zieht man das *heute* im subjektlosen Passiv ins Vorfeld, verschwindet das *es.* Seine einzige Aufgabe besteht darin, das Vorfeld in Ermangelung eines Subjekts zu besetzen. Das würde ich »syntaktischen Expletiv« nennen. Im Gegensatz dazu ist das *es* in »Heute regnet es« *nicht* entfallen; es dient in diesem Satz als Subjekt, auch wenn es dort ein reiner Platzhalter ist. Weil es grammatikalisch (und nicht rein syntaktisch) notwendig ist, möchte ich es »grammatikalischen Expletiv« nennen.

Das *es* in »es braucht« ist, wie man anhand deiner Beispiele sehen kann, grammatikalisch notwendig; es bleibt auch erhalten, wenn es nicht im Vorfeld steht.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung!

Answer (score 5):

Es scheit so, also ob diese Formulierung im südlichen und südwestlichen Sprachraum schon seit langer Zeit verwendet würde:

```
Der Rhein, ist seitwärts Hinweggegangen. 
Umsonst nicht gehn 
Im Trocknen die Ströme. 
Aber wie? Ein Zeichen braucht es,
Nichts anderes, schlecht und recht, damit es Sonn
Und Mond trag im Gemüt, untrennbar,
```

(Hölderlin, Der Ister, 1804)

Nachdem es hier Leute zu geben scheint, denen Hölderlins Sprache nicht repräsentativ genug ist für die deutsche Sprache, noch ein Schiller-Zitat (der dürfte über mehr Zweifel erhaben sein):

> Es braucht der Waffen nicht!

(Wallenstein)

Genügt das immer noch nicht, nehmen wir halt den Dichterfürsten:

> Alles was es braucht auf dieser Welt ist ein gescheiter Einfall und ein fester Entschluss.

Das ist sicher kein Anglizismus, wie in anderen Antworten vermutet (das Englische hat kein solches Konstrukt), sondern möglicherweise durch französischen Spracheinfluß entstanden ("il faut").

In meiner täglichen Spracherfahrung kommt das durchaus täglich vor.

Vollkommen gängig ist "Es braucht" z.B. in Ausdrücken wie

> Es wird noch Jahre brauchen, bis sich die Wirtschaft von der Pandemie erholt hat.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich habt ihr auch „es hat“, während wir nur „es gibt“ benutzen.

Comment: @CarstenS Natürlich: "Hat's noch Eier im Kühlschrank?" ist vollkommen gebräuchlich.

Comment: Ich denke, der Sprachgebrauch von Hölderlin ist generell nicht besonders geeignet, um die Gebräuchlichkeit von Redeweisen zu untersuchen. Spezifisch wäre überdies in dem Beispiel "Ein Zeichen braucht man" sinnentstellend. Daher halte ich den Beleg für unpassend.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das musst du mir erklären. Wenn ich mich recht entsinne, ist Hölderlin ein deutscher Dichter, der in deutscher Sprache gedichtet hat. Inwiefern er dann nicht als Beleg geeignet sein soll, ist mir schleierhaft.

Comment: Seine Gedichte sind in einer sehr individuellen, poetisch überformten Sprechweise geschrieben. Das Beispiel belegt, dass die Konstruktion im Deutschen möglich ist. Das war aber gar nicht strittig. Das Beispiel belegt nicht, dass die Redeweise gebräuchlich war, auch nicht im süddeutschen Raum. Ich sage auch nicht, dass das Beispiel die These wiederlegt, sondern nur, dass es ein sehr schwacher Beleg für die These ist. Mitnichten wollte ich zum Ausdruck bringen, dass "Hölderlin nicht deutsch genug ist" (was immer das bedeuten soll). Ich denke, die Antwort hat durch die weiteren Beispiele ewonnen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Dein zweites Argument "ein Zeichen braucht man" wäre sinnentstellend, stellt ja eigentlich grade heraus, das es "es braucht" im Deutschen braucht [sic].

Comment: Wir reden aneinander vorbei. Ich meine, dass es nicht gefragt war, ob "es braucht" im Deutschen exisitiert. Die Frage war doch, ob "es braucht" im Vergleich zur Alternative "man braucht" zunehmend verwendet wird. Darüber geben einzelne Zitate aus literarischen Texten keinen Aufschluss. Aber mir scheint, du wolltest mit deinem Beitrag etwas anderes zeigen - nämlich, dass es die Formulierung überhaupt gibt. Ich hatte implizit angenommen, dass dein Beitrag eine Antwort auf die Frage geben will, wie ich sie verstehe. Aber da liegt wohl das Missverständnis und deshalb reden wir aneinander vorbei

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Die Frage von Hubert (ob "es braucht..." eine neuzeitliche Entwicklung ist), lässt sich am besten mit historischen Texten beantworten. Da Korpora aus dem 18. Jhd. ein bißchen rar sind, halte ich literarische Texte immer noch für das nächstbeste Mittel.

Answer (score 1):

Komme aus Südbaden, nahe der Grenze zur Schweiz. Für mich ist "es braucht" ganz natürlich. Bin noch jünger, kann daher zur Historie nicht so viel beitragen. Mir schwätzet hier alemannische Dialekt (alemannisch bezeichnet nicht nur den Dialekt in Südbaden, sondern ist auch der Oberbegriff für Schweizerdeutsch, Schwäbisch und die Dialekte in Vorarlberg und Liechtenstein).

Typische tägliche Ausdrücke wären: "Bruuchts des?" (Braucht es das? = Ist das nötig?). oder z.B.: "Es braucht Wasser und Salz zum Backen der Wecken."

Könnte mir vorstellen, dass sich das über Vorarlberg in den restlichen österreichischen Sprachraum eingeschlichen hat.

Answer (score 0):

"Es braucht" war vor 20 Jahren in Österreich völlig ungebräuchlich, hat sich seither aber epidemieartig ausgebreitet. Meine Theorie ist, dass MAN im Zuge der Suche nach einer "geschlechtsneutralen" Alternative für das ach so maskuline "man" in den alemannischen Dialektraum geschielt hat, wo "es braucht" in seiner Verwandtschaft mit dem französischen "il faut" durchaus plausibel ist.
Also: ein mainstream-gender-affiner Import aus Westgermanistan!

Comment: Gewagte Theorie ... Gegenbeispiel wäre z. B. dass "braucht's des" von Gerhard Polt spätestens in den 90ern in einer seiner Nummern verwendet wurde, in der er als konservativer Redner auftritt (wenn ich mich recht erinnere). Mit Gender-Sensibilität hat es ziemlich sicher rein gar nix zu tun.

Comment: Natürlich ist alles möglich, aber die gender-Neutralität braucht es nicht als Erklärung. Statt "Wenn das so ist, dann braucht man keine Regierung mehr" braucht man/frau nur "Wenn das so ist, dann brauchen wir keine Regierung mehr" zu sagen. Es sei denn, das Wort *wir* müsste dringend durch etwas etwas ersetzt werden, das nicht so männerbündlerisch klingt.

Answer (score -1):

Ich habe die Hälfte meines Lebens (66) an unterschiedlichen Orten in Deutschland gelebt, Süd wie Nord, auch nahe an der Grenze zur Schweiz und zu Österreich. "Es braucht" ist mir dort bis vor rund 15 bis 20 Jahren nicht begegnet. Auch nicht in den jeweiligen Mundarten. Meine Theorie ist, dass "es braucht" ein Anglizismus ist und aus der wörtlichen Übersetzung von "it needs" herrührt, was im Englischen für "es besteht die Notwendigkeit für ..." oder ähnliche Wendungen gebraucht wird.

Comment: Kannst du ein paar Beispiele für die englische Formulierung geben? Ich komme momentan nur auf zwei Fälle (und finde auch nur diese Fälle in Google), welche beide erhebliche strukturelle Unterschiede zum genannten "Es braucht" aufweisen: 1) "It needs to be/get <Verb>ed" - in der Tat sehr gebräuchlich, lässt sich aber eben gerade *nicht* mit einer Nominalphrase wie das deutsche "es braucht" verwenden. 2) "It needs <Substantiv>" - ebenfalls gebräuchlich, aber dies wiederum *nur*, wenn "it" sich auf ein konkretes im sächliches Substantiv bezieht und nicht, wie in "es braucht", unpersönlich ist.

Comment: Ein Anglizismus scheint mir auch weniger wahrscheinlich, sondern wenn eher ein Gallizismus. Im Französischen gibt es die Wendung « il faut ... » , zum Beispiel in « Il faut un livre » für "Man braucht ein Buch" oder « Il faut manger » für "Man muss essen". Das geht soweit, dass andere Personen als Objekte verwendet werden, zum Beispiel « Il me faut un pain » für "Ich brauche ein Brot" (wörtlich ungefähr "Es braucht mir ein Brot"). Das würde auch mit der Einschätzung korrellieren, dass "es braucht" eher im Süd_westen_ des deutschen Sprachraums auftaucht bzw. sich von dort ausbreitet.